# Insert current date in column when conditions are met using excel function

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to update cell I3's value to today's date when my other conditions are met. However, I see only ZERO is updated in cell I3. I also want H3 to become static because it has real feed dates from Database. Below is my formula:

```
=IF(AND(G3>=F3,H3=TODAY()), IF(I3="", TODAY(), I3), "")
```

|  | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Target | High | today |  |
| 3 | 1320 | 1320 | 11/16/23 |  |

[image]

Comment: You can't update a value by formula. In which cell do you put the formula?

Comment: I column I have put formula. My expectation is I3 column should get replaced with Today's date and H3 should not gets updated further as above code just a POC as I am having real time feed in my actual excel.

Comment: If you put the formula in cell I3 you will get a circular reference. Try to better describe - in your question, not in the comments! - what your situation and your true _requirement_ is.

Comment: So to make H3 fixed, then copy paste.special values.

Comment: A formula calculates and doesn't, so if something changes.. it calculates. Since `TODAY()` is subject to system time (outside of Excel itself) Excel needs to recheck the condition for TODAY anytime something changes in the file. Making it volatile, but also making it impossible to lock the value. You need to use vba to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using iterative calculations. In File -> Options -> Formulas, check "Enable iterative calculations" and set the max value to something small, like 2. Make sure calculation options are set to "Automatic" as well. Then, the formula to type into cell I3 would be:

```
=IF(G3 >= F3, IF(NUMBERVALUE(I3) > 0, I3, TODAY()), "")
```

Note that column H is not needed for the actual calculation.

Checking its own value allows for a kind of "soft locking" of the cell value so it doesn't get updated by the volatile `TODAY()` function. However, note that if you update the formula, the date will reset.

Comment: Wow. lovely. Much appreciated.

Comment: Certainly! If it worked for you, feel free to accept the answer.